# Keeping folders automatically sync'd on a Windows machine

Tags: windows

Is there a way to automatically keep two folders in sync (or mirrored) in real-time on a Windows machine?

Does any one know of any free software / windows tool for doing this?

Cheers,
Nick.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Bi-directional or Uni-directional?

Comment: I assume from your question, this is on a single PC. In which case, I have to ask why would you want to do this?

Comment: Yes - you're right, just on one machine. Uni-directional. One of the folders is an external Network attached HDD. The files are critical, so when I copy them there - I'd like for a backup to be made immediately with some tool that watches the folder. Sorry if the question wasn't particularly clear!

Comment: If it was a server I'd recommend DFS.  For just a single PC you're probably better off going to SuperUser.

Comment: Why not just setup RAID1?

Comment: DFS itself doesn't offer any replication. DFSR does, however this doesn't work on a single server, it requires a pair of servers (2003 R2 or later). RAID1 isn't a backup solution. You delete the file on one member (whoops) and the second member also loses the copy.

Answer (score 6):

[robocopy.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9D467A69-57FF-4AE7-96EE-B18C4790CFFD&displaylang=en) is part of the Windows 2003 Server Resource Kit.  One of the switches (/MON:n) puts it into monitor mode, in which re-runs after it sees n files change.  If you set n to 1, you should be able to accomplish what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at using a tool such as Synctoy, Live Sync or Live Mesh, or even Dropbox.  It doesn't copy the data in real-time but it's near real time and should be plenty fast since your doing it across local storage.  Here's is a quick rundown review of Live Sync and Live Mesh: http://www.labnol.org/internet/compare-windows-live-sync-mesh-and-skydrive/6166/. Dropbox has a similar ability using the SyncUSBDrive add-on feature; some info on it can be found in their wiki [here](http://wiki.dropbox.com/TipsAndTricks/SyncUSBDrive)

They are all free and here is the official downloads:

- http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx
- http://www.mesh.com/
- http://sync.live.com/
- http://www.dropbox.com/

Answer (score 0):

[**SyncBack Pro**](http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/sbpro-features.html) has such a feature: each time a file is changed in the source directory, it will be copied to the destination, if you select the right options in the settings of the profile:

[image]